# Choices-js re-initialise select element

Tags: javascript

I have a select element containing years related to the data being returned. I have a search function that will filter the data returned and therefor change the year values that should be in the select element.

I am using the Choices-js: https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices

Get list of years for select element:

```
function get_date_filter_data() {
    $.ajax({
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken },
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/v1/dates/',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        cache: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({query: '{datesList(search:"' + search + '", showDigital:' + show_digital + ', showPromo:' + show_digital + ')}'}),
        success: function (result) {
            data_filter_list = result['data']['datesList']
            set_date_filter_data(data_filter_list)
        },
    })
}
```

Set year values for select element:

```
function set_date_filter_data(data) {
    console.log(year)
    let filter_options = ''
    filter_options += '<option value="all">All</option>'
    $.each(data, function (_a, b) {
        filter_options += '<option value="' + b + '">' + b + '</option>'
    });
    document.getElementById('choices-year').innerHTML = filter_options
    if (year == ''){
        selectChoice('choices-year', 'all')
    } else {
        selectChoice('choices-year', year)
    }
    
    if (document.getElementById('choices-year')) {
        var element = document.getElementById('choices-year');
        const example = new Choices(element, {
            searchEnabled: true,
            searchPlaceholderValue: 'Search',
            itemSelectText: '',
            shouldSort: false,
        });
    };
}
```

When the page is loaded it calls the API which returns all years. However, running `get_date_filter_data` with search value set to something. It returns the subset of years for the value the user has searched for.

Even though the user has search for something and the `data_filter_list` is now a smaller subset of years, the select element doesn't update with a warning stating:

> Trying to initialise Choices on element already initialised

How do I get it to force a re-initialise?